# Does phonegap/cordova's Media class overcome the limitations of iOS/android audio in html5?

Tags: android, ios, html, audio, cordova

I've been reading about [the limitations of html5 on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/audiovideo/conceptual/using_html5_audio_video/device-specificconsiderations/device-specificconsiderations.html).  Apparently I can only play one file at a time and you can only play audio as a reaction to a user event.  This is pretty disheartening because I'm trying to make a relatively high quality game in html5, and background music *and* sound effects are expected.  I'm now looking for workarounds to accomplish this.

I'm wondering if PhoneGap/Cordova could provide that workaround.  It seems to have a [Media object](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_media_media.md.html).  But this link is a reference, not a tutorial.  I'm having trouble finding documentation on whether it overcomes the html5 limitations or is the same/worse.  As my app currently has nothing to do with PhoneGap, I would like to know if PhoneGap can support audio features that a game demands before I put in a bunch of effort to try it out.  Here's what I'd need:

1. The ability to play background audio while other audio plays.  IE: Background music and multiple sound effects at the same time
2. The ability to play audio without user interaction first (This is a want, not a need)

Can phonegap provide this functionality?  If so, I'd like some sample code to show how it's done.

Comment: I'm looking into something similar - I'm using the howler.js Javascript library to fire off the audio.  I'm using both a background loop and audio sprites.  I will say - on my iPad 3 (and newer) it works great; lots of sprites can play at one time with no conflict at all.  On iPad generations 1 and 2, huge problems.  The game freezes up when I play audio.  I'm curious to know if you've found anything that has helped you use audio in the way that you want . . .

Comment: @blaster not yet.  I've done everything I can to avoid audio as long as possible.  I'm still avoiding it.

Comment: I was also thinking of trying Cordova's Media object to play sounds instead of using the webbish HTML5 audio approach.  Have you tried that yet?

Comment: @blaster no.  Isn't that what my question is asking?

Comment: Yes - since you'd posted it three months ago I wondered if you'd tried it in the meantime . . .

Comment: @blaster not yet. I already said I hadn't yet when I replied to you on the 16th.

Comment: Apologies for the misunderstanding.  Hey, check this out - very interesting solution that isn't specific to Phonegap development, but provides a way to get multiple audio sprites working in HTML5 on iOS5 specifically: http://remysharp.com/2010/12/23/audio-sprites/

Comment: @blaster from what I understand, this seems to work with the limitations rather than overcome them: I see no evidence that he's figured out how to play multiple tracks at once.  EG: He can't have a sound effect during background music with this solution.

Comment: True.  Hey, last night I finally hooked up the Cordova Media object and it does work with multiple simultaneous sounds - it does seem to introduce some lagginess on a 1st-gen iOS5 iPad (it's an Angular app so it runs $digests frequently) but it was a big improvement!

Comment: For some reason I don't understand, @jollycic's post was deleted, but he provided these two links: http://www.tricedesigns.com/2012/01/25/low-latency-polyphonic-audio-in-phonegap/ and https://github.com/triceam/LowLatencyAudio

Answer (score 2):

Cordova's `Media` class is pretty limited, I've had some luck with plugins such as https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-lowlatencyaudio